# PHP Foreach inside variable with equals

Tags: php, foreach, echo, var

I have a variable that equals some simple data as shown below

```
$var = 'hello names here how are yous?';
```

what i wish to achieve is have a foreach loop inside the $var but i have tried various ways with just no luck, always throwing errors.

Below is somewhat what i what to do.

```
$var = 'hello '.foreach($datas as $data) { echo $data }.' how are yous?';
echo $var;
```

which would output - hello Mike Daniel Steve how are yous?

any help appreciated.

======EDIT========
im trying to write to file the looped contents with below code.

```
  $datas = 'Name, Name2, Name4';
  $var = ''.foreach($datas as $data) { echo $data }.'

 $default_file = 'media/default.php';
 $default_file_handle = fopen($default_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$default_file);


$default_data = '
'.$var.'//each value to be a new line
Name2 //example
Name4 //example
etc
';
fwrite($default_file_handle, $default_data);
```

so basically im write to file each value in the loop to a new line. I can write just normal content but getting a loop in their im struggling with

Comment: Just get rid of the thought that it could or should be done in one line and build the result string incrementally by appending to it.

Comment: You cannot assign a loop in a variabele

Answer (score 5):

```
$var = 'hello';
foreach($datas as $data) {
  $var .= ' '.$data.' ';
}
$var .= ' how are you?';
echo $var;
```

that should do it

Answer (score 4):

```
$arr = array("Mike", "John");
echo "Hello " . implode(" ", $arr) . ", how are you?";
```

`implode` is your friend. Implode joins array elements together into one single string. The separator between each array element is the first parameter - in this case a blank.

Comment: Since I think this is the best answer I suggest giving a brief description on how implode works. Otherwise newbies might see it as "magic" with a puzzled look. You have to teach them how to fish, not fish for them. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `implode`:

```
$var = 'hello '.implode(' ', $datas) .' how are yous?';
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you either have to insert the foreach loop like this:

```
echo "hello ";
foreach($datas as $data) {
    echo $data;
}
echo " how are you?";
```

or you can use an extra variable and the [implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) method:

```
$dataString = implode(" ", $datas);
echo "hello " . $dataString . " how are you?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this following way.

```
<?php 

 $data = array('Mike Daniel','john doe');

 foreach ($data as $value) {
    $result = 'hello '. $value. ' how are you?'. '</br>'; 
    echo  $result;
 }
```